# Is the plural of the electronic mouse "mouses" or "mice"?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

Is the plural of that device that you plug into your computer *mouses* or *mice*? Which of these is correct?

> I bought some wireless optical mouses for my colleagues at work.
>
> I bought some wireless optical mice for my colleagues at work.

I prefer the first one though I'm not sure why. The second makes me think there are some weird mutated creatures running around under my desk.

Comment: I've always used [meeses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixie_and_Dixie_and_Mr._Jinks).

Comment: The pointing device was named a mouse because it looks like one.  There really isn't any logic to use a different plural than mice.  Is it "correct"?  Any word that gets used often enough will work its way into the dictionary.  The better question would be "is it correct yet?"

Comment: An earlier question with more answers: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9836/11504

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both plurals are correct. ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mouse).) I don't have access to *Oxford English Dictionary* at the moment (or don't know where to find it), but according to [Answers.com](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_plural_of_%27mouse%27_on_a_computer), the *OED* concurs. So use whichever one you wish.

Comment: +1 Even though I prefer the term "mouses" to distinguish between the gizmo and the mammal, that's just me being fussy. Either is acceptable and almost invariably understood in context. The only time you might want to make a distinction is when there is a real chance for confusion, as in a lab setting where the behavior of mice is studied and the results are tabulated with "the click of a mouse." Even then you might simply specify that the lab needed, say, more *computer* mice if many weren't functioning correctly.

Comment: The Second Edition of the OED gives one plural quote, which has "mice"; in the Third Edition (November 2010), the old quote is gone and there is a new plural quote, which has "mouses". It seems they jumbled quotes for no reason. The entry says nothing about the plural besides these quotes, so I feel that we cannot draw any conclusion about which form the OED supports.