# Bigfoots or Bigfeet?

Tags: grammatical-number

I was reading a book called *[Bigfoot vs. Chupacabra](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17271442-bigfoot-vs-chupacabra)* in which this issue was raised.  I suspect it derives from Tolkien, per the [Proudfoots vs. Proudfeet](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Proudfoot) dispute.

- What is the proper plural of the colloquial American term for [Sasquatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigfoot)?

The book also touches on [Yeti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeti), which seems to be both singular and plural, although "Yetis" is proposed as a correct, if less graceful, alternative. I mention it because there may be a plural usage for Bigfoot: *"Stay away from the crick--there's a herd of Bigfoot down there eatin' blueberry bagels."*

As I am regularly accused of assaulting the English language, I though I'd bring it to the experts.

---

This question on "mouses vs. mice" provides some very good insight, but I'm also interested in these specific terms, and the idea of the plural use of the singular form, thus Yeti/Yeti/Yetis. (In other words, it also relates to deer and deer (singular and plural, respectively.)

Comment: The [Wiktionary entry for **sawtooth**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sawtooth) << sawtooth (plural sawteeth or sawtooths) [a] (plural "sawteeth") A cutting bit of a saw. // [b] (plural "sawtooths") sawtooth wave >> illustrates the problem with solid compounds whose head forms an irregular plural. The only ways to decide these tricky problems: (1) explore reference works which use a certain variant, or, if these aren't available, (2) see which way most reasonably competent Anglophones opt (in a Google search, say).

Comment: _Invariant plurals for animals_ has already been covered at [Why is the plural of “deer” the same as the singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188578/why-is-the-plural-of-deer-the-same-as-the-singular).

Comment: And [When is it correct to not use the irregular form for a plural – eg mouses vs mice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9836/when-is-it-correct-to-not-use-the-irregular-form-for-a-plural-e-g-mouses-vs-m) asks the general question you particularise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for linking "[deer/deer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/188588/216884)".  Useful and highly interesting.  However that answer is related to a neuter declension of an ancient word, thus comments on, but does not provide a direct answer, to the question in relation to *very popular* modern word.  (Also neither related questions mention Tolkien, who had an impressive command of language, and was surely the inspiration for the Bigfoot/Bigfeet conundrum;)

Comment: I should think the Sawtooth Mountains were known as the Sawtooths way before Bilbo's farewell party. In fact, [a Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Proudfoots&year_start=1800&year_end=1910&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CProudfoots%3B%2Cc0) shows that 'Proudfoots' itself had been used by 1836.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's the spirit!  *(My reading was that Tolkien did not have much regard for those who held Proudfeet to be correct ;)*

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't post [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bigfoots%2CBigfeet&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBigfoots%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBigfeet%3B%2Cc0) yourself. 'Bigfeet' seems to be on the up.

Comment: The correct plural is clearly octopi... I mean, Bigfooti.

Comment: Why would Bigfoot need a plural form, when there's only one of him?

Comment: this is an old conundrum.  what is the plural of "tenderfoot"?

Comment: Curious that you consider "Sasquatch" to be the more formal alternative to "Bigfoot."

Comment: @Azor-Ahai great comment.  See: [Etymology of Sasquatch](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sasquatch)  I also find Sasquatch quite attractive because it can be both singular and plural.

Answer (score 12):

There isn't really any way to define a "proper" plural for a *colloquial* term for a mythical creature.

English plural formation, although mostly regular, permits an indefinite amount of irregularity for any particular word. Consider the case of *people,* which is, at least from an etymological standpoint, a [suppletive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) plural form of *person* that is not related at all (from a synchronic standpoint, I suppose the initial "p" that  these words have in common could be considered a shared element, although it's not clear what type of element it would be).

From what I understand, a hypothesis has been proposed that plurals or other inflected forms have to be formed regularly if they are compounds and the last element is not the semantic head, but there isn't clear evidence that this hypothesis is true and there are a fair amount of counterexamples. To me, it seems more like an argument based on the logic of how it *seems* pluralization should work than an actual established fact about how pluralization *does* work. See the following *Language Log* posts by Mark Liberman:

- [Systematic Irregularization](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/004151.html)
- [Flew v. Flied](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4211)

In a whimsical context, someone might even use an "improper" form deliberately: does that mean it should be considered "proper" in a way after all? It just seems like a matter of opinion to me. (E.g. consider the relatively common fanciful forms "meese" and "mongeese", or the form "mie" in the couplet "A cube of cheese no larger than a die, may bait the trap to catch a nibbling mie" ([Ambrose Bierce](https://books.google.com/books?id=ESpUXpqO55QC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=A%20cube%20of%20cheese%20no%20larger%20than%20a%20die%20May%20bait%20the%20trap%20to%20catch%20a%20nibbling%20mie&source=bl&ots=swgN-Uyg_n&sig=v_DdyZuXnPt34CZHZd4IJq7SWkQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3vZXUwePUAhXn7oMKHXaGD0EQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=A%20cube%20of%20cheese%20no%20larger%20than%20a%20die%20May%20bait%20the%20trap%20to%20catch%20a%20nibbling%20mie&f=false), attributed to "that eminent poet and domestic economist, Senator Depew".)

Comment: Thank you!  This is very informative.  I suspected the authors were being playful.  (I re-read the Hobbit recently and noted a degree of post-modernism.  The re-reading also rekindled an awareness of how whimsical Tolkien could be, an element often overlooked per the "heaviness" of LoTR;)

Answer (score 11):

In this case I would choose "Bigfoots." As in, "Three Bigfoots were spotted in the Sierra Nevada mountains over the weekend."

If you say it the other way, it is confusing: "Three Bigfeet were spotted...."

Comment: [Monsters Among Us: An Exploration of Otherworldly **Bigfoots**, Wolfmen, Portals](https://books.google.it/books?id=i9yACwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=bigfoots&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bigfoots&f=false) Bravo for sticking your neck out!

Comment: (1) Stress patterns would differentiate. (2) As Matt Gutting has said: 'What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case an encyclopedia, dictionary, or some other such document). Edit your question and put in your support ...' / Answers without supporting references are indistinguishable from (and perhaps only) personal opinion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Bigfoots, but Wolfmen?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Yes, b/c wolfmen are men, of a sort, but bigfoots are not a sort of foot.