# New words with Apophonic plurals

Tags: nouns, irregular-plurals, i-mutation

I was wondering if new words or neologisms have been formed with apophonic plurals such as;

foot->feet
mouse->mice
goose->geese

I am not searching for nouns that were influenced by the i-mutation but words created recently and having the same type of plural form.

Comment: It's unlikely; the move is towards standardisation. Thus 'Sawtooths', the fairly infrequent 'mouses'. And thus related: [When is it correct to not use the irregular form for a plural eg 'mouses' vs 'mice'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9836/when-is-it-correct-to-not-use-the-irregular-form-for-a-plural-e-g-mouses-vs-m). (And if by 'or neologisms' is intended 'or D-I-Y candidates', please note that such are off-topic.)

Comment: @Lux Could you indicate, in your question, where else you have searched? Were the example words in some particular list? If posible give some pointers.