# Plural of table leaf

Tags: word-usage, nouns, grammatical-number, morphology, inflectional-morphology

In the context of a table leaf, what is the correct plural term, "table leafs" or "table leaves"?

Comment: Some modern usages do pluralise regularly (eg computer mouses), but have you checked this one in a dictionary? Look at how AHDEL and RHK Webster's handle the plurals of mouse (though admittedly they disagree, and with Collins!)

Comment: I've seen both.

Comment: @David M: I've seen 'Gerroff!", but I wouldn't advise using it very often.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why not?  It might make you the most interesting person at a cocktail party!

Comment: A pair of [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=table+leaves%2Ctable+leafs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctable%20leaves%3B%2Cc0) seems to indicate that only one of the variants David has seen would not be considered non-standard.

Comment: I have never called them, nor would ever dream of calling them, anything other than 'table leaves'.

Comment: Yes, I've been told to "put the leaves in the table" or some such on several occasions.  Never has it been "leafs".

Comment: As anyone who has spent time in Canada can tell you, the primary circumstance in which a North American might use "leafs" is in connection with the professional hockey team that represents Toronto in the NHL: the Maple Leafs. Or perhaps when referring to an urbane panda presented with an overrated book on punctuation usage: It eats shoots and leafs through the text.

Comment: When we're talking about Software Defined networking, with Spine and Leaf switches. My feeling is 'Leafs' sounds better but I can't explain why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Merriam-Webster's online dictionary either is a correct plural for the word leaf.  There is no differentiation between the usages.

[The usage of the word for part of a table is that it is suggestive of a leaf.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leafs)  Hence, it follows the same usage.

Though, I must say that more and more sources I've looked at prefer *leaves* as the plural of leaf (in any usage). [Example](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/leaf_3)

Comment: No, the logic falls down, as 'the reason the word _mouse_ is used for the computer controller is that it is suggestive of a mouse (of the small mammal variety) yet the plural _mouses_ is in common use. More recent new senses tend to have more standard pluralisation or conjugation chosen for them. Though 'mice' is also used for the computer controllers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've always taken exception to the usage of mouses as being a bit . . . contrived?  I'm using the test case of the leaves of a book as an example.

Comment: We've covered this before. [Here](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004151.html) is an article on ' "Systematic regularization" [which] is one of several different terms used to name a familiar phenomenon, long noted in English and some other languages as well. Sometimes, a morphologically-irregular word form becomes regularized when the word is used in a new way ...' Table leaves were given the name before this practice really began to gain momentum.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't dispute that it is true.  I've just always hated it for computer mice.  It's a peeve, not a fact.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a rant to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't believe I'm ranting.  It's not that heated of a subject for me.  For example, I've never slapped anyone over the usage.

Comment: A rant is a peeve (your word) expressed on the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Rant implies a tirade that goes on at length.  I was just stating my personal distaste for the one usage.

Comment: Could a dictionary reference ('the dictionary' is virtually meaningless and certainly unhelpful here) be given licensing the plural 'leafs'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The link (which has always been present) is a direct reference to said reference. And, I've changed the wording.

Comment: Ah, the link was disguised; I didn't guess it was to a plural. [This article](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101001232046AAShPvT) mentions the M-W listing of the alternative 'leafs', but adds: "... the OED, which is considered by many to be the authority on correct English usage, lists only 'leaves' as the plural of 'leaf'. " The article I linked to on regularisation mentions that 'Factories churn out Barbies, Mickey Mouses (*Mickey Mice) and Ninja Turtles.' And "Brian Pierce flied out (*flew out) to center to end the inning." But these instances are (perhaps mercifully) rare.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I've never called a plurality of mouse-like Human Interface Devices anything other than "mice", and don't recall anyone else doing so, except in jest.

Comment: @Hot Licks 'The online Oxford Dictionaries entry for mouse states the plural for the small rodent is _mice_, while the plural for the small computer connected device is either _mice_ or _mouses_.'  They use bigger samples than you seem to.

Comment: This has also been covered before on ELU at [Is the plural of the electronic mouse “mouses” or “mice”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/is-the-plural-of-the-electronic-mouse-mouses-or-mice). OED has given both plural forms.

Comment: There are also the [Toronto Maple Leafs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Maple_Leafs)